# What is the best way to print screens from an ASP.NET page .NET1.1/.NET2.0

Tags: printing, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-1.1

I have seen examples of printing from a windows application but I have not been able to find a good example of any way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean print screens ? If you want to print the page, asp.net or not, it's up to the browser to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the print style sheet

here's and article http://alistapart.com/stories/goingtoprint/ that will go through the way to set that up.  Rather than setting up a special page that would need to be maintained as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to print your web page from the client-side use `window.print()`. Sample could be found here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml. I would suggest preparing a special version of your page first with no dynamic content and with a layout which would look nice on print.

If you need to send something to printer on the server-side that would be a *little bit* more complicated. Check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188767.aspx) article on how to do the basic printing.

Answer (score 0):

The browser prints your pages.  If you need to tweak the page so it looks better on the printer, use CSS @media selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Restating what others have said, you just need to call window.print() in javascript. That and build a separate css for print.